# How to apply time.sleep() in a lambda function of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am translating large amounts of text using [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/). But I keep getting this error `Unexpected status code "429" from ('translate.google.com',)` as I am making a lot of requests. So what I am trying to do is call `time.sleep(1)` after every translation is done to try and see if this will solve it.

Now I know I could do this with a for-loop where I would just loop over the text in the column `tweet_text`, translate the word and then sleep for a second.

But I am trying to figure out how I would incorporate the `time.sleep(1)` within the lambda function that translates the words in the code below.

```
df_bdtu['translated_tweet_text'] = df_bdtu['tweet_text'].swifter.apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest="en"))
```

Comment: I think you are probably will need to create a function containing the sleep that you `apply()`. Others might have something better to offer though

Comment: To avoid to many requests, you could rethink your code to be able to use the `Advanced Usage (Bulk)` from the link of `googletrans` you provided, something like `df_bdtu['translated_tweet_text'] = translator.translate(df_bdtu['tweet_text'].tolist())`. But if you end up using your way with a `time.sleep` somewhere, then using `swifter` becomes a bit counterproductive :)

Comment: @Ben.T I see is it because `swifter` is faster than using `apply()` from pandas which cancels out the time spent sleeping?

Comment: @yudhiesh of what I understand of swifter, yes if you use it to speed up the apply but need to use time.sleep to prevent doing to many requests in a short period of time, they have opposite effect :)

Comment: @Ben.T thanks will try it without swifter and in its own function then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So even with `time.sleep()` and removing the use of `swifter` the issue still persisted. I ended up trying 3 different libraries but they either had the same problem where I was making too many request or they were not able to process the emojis in the data I had.

I landed on this library [deep-translator](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator) which was able to use the same code with swifter and translate about 5000 rows of tweets in roughly 15 minutes.

```
def translate_(x):
  if x['lang'] != 'en':
    text = x['tweet_text']
    translated = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(text) 
    return translated

df_bdtu['translated_tweet_text'] = df_bdtu.swifter.apply(translate_,axis=1)
```